# Swift Package Manager - Framework Distribution

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

We are trying to export our dynamic framework via SwiftPM.

We would like to export it as a final product, that is, a ".framework" file and *not* the source files (which need to be hidden).

In the documentation in SPM and other places on the Internet, we could not find a way to do that, unless we open a repository in GitHub
and upload our files to it.

Is there another way? Or is it just a code sharing tool for now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible with SwiftPM. There are a few of us that are working on a proposal to support such a feature. It is being discussed on the forums a bit over [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/spm-support-for-binaries-distribution/25549).